# If $f(x) = 2x^4-15x^3+ax^2+bx+c$, then if $(x-5)^2$ is a factor of $f$, then $f^{'}(5)=0$.

Tags: derivatives, roots

Let $f(x) = 2x^4-15x^3+ax^2+bx+c$, then if $(x-5)^2$ is a factor of $f$, then $f^{'}(5)=0$.

It is not immediately obvious why this is so, since this question is only awarded 1 mark. I actually have to let $f(x) = (x-5)^2(x-k_1)(x-k_2)$ and differentiate to find the answer. The product rule guarantees that the derivative will contain $x-5$, hence the answer.

but given it is 1 mark in an IB exam, is there any easier way?

Comment: What is the connection between $f$ and $P$?

Comment: 5 is a repeated roots so the result follows

Comment: Your way is correct. Can you immediately see why the derivative has to be zero at 5? The question gives a lot of extraneous information with the 2, 15, a, b, c.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Double_Root_of_Polynomial_is_Root_of_Derivative

Comment: It is completely irrelevant that $\;f\;$ is a quartic. This is true for any polynomial (which, of course, must be *at least* of degree two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $f(x)=0$ has one double root say $r$ $\implies f(r)=0=f'(r)$ and $(x-r)^2$ is a factor of $f(x)$.
Geometrically, at $x=r$, $y=f(x)$ touches the $x$-axis at $x=r$.